# Contexto de Sincronização Aspnet Core (deadlock)

Tags: c#, async, asp-net-core

Eu tive um problema com deadlock no meu código em .Net framework, segue abaixo o trecho dele:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
     AsyncCall().Wait();
​     return Ok("Ok");
}
​
private async Task AsyncCall()
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
}
```

Eu consegui resolver o problema, utilizando o `.ConfigureAwait(false)`, porém o mesmo código, sem o `.ConfigureAwait(false)` funciona em um projeto Aspnet Core.

Gostaria de entender o motivo dele funcionar em .Net Core, e no Framework causar deadlock. Eu li que no Core não há Contexto de Sincronização, porém não entendi o que isso significa.

Comment: O que exatamente você está querendo fazer?

Comment: O que não entendi exatamente foi o motivo do código causar deadlock no .Net, mas no Core isso não acontecer. O problema foi resolvido com o .ConfigureAwait(false) no framework. Gostaria de entender melhor o que ocorre no .Net Core para que isso não ocorra.